# If $X $ is distributed as $ U(0,1)$ what is the distribution of $Y = X^3$?

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, probability-distributions

If $X $ is distributed as $ U(0,1)$ what is the distribution of $Y = X^3$?. I have managed to find that, since for $ x \in [0,1]$ we ahve that $g(x) = x^3$ is strictly monotone, then the distribution function is $f_Y(y) = 1/3 y^{-2/3}$ but I can't recognise this as any standard distribution?

Comment: Why should it be a standard distribution?

Comment: It asks me to find the distribution of $Y$, not the probability density function of $Y$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'standard distribution'? Do you mean just a generally known distribution?

Comment: yes sorry I mean generally known distribution. I might have made a mistake with my calculation of the pdf, but I don't htink so

Comment: @waterbottle what is "distribution of Y"? In some books the "distribution" is refered to the CPF and in others to PDF or PMF.

Comment: I am not sure how to explain it, but take $X$ for example, the distribution of $X$ is the uniform distribution from 0 to 1

Comment: @waterbottle this is the pdf or pmf.

Comment: OK - so I have found the pdf - is that it? is it correct?

Comment: It is a very special instance of a **beta distribution**. And yes you have the right formula, except you should specify where the formula holds, and where the density is $0$.

Comment: hmm I don't see how it is the beta function? I have that $f_Y(y) = 1/3 y^{-2/3}$ for $y \in (0,1]$ and 0 otherwise

Comment: @waterbottle So you have $f_Y(y) = \dfrac{y^{1/3 - 1}(1-y)^{1-1}}{\beta(1/3,1)}\mathbf 1_{y\in(0,1]}$ ?... looks like $Y\sim\mathcal{\beta eta}(1/3, 1)$ to me. $~$  **Note:** $\beta(a, 1) = 1/a$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general transforms of well-known distributions are not always well known distributions.  But in the particular case where $X$ is uniform on [0, 1], $Y = X^n$ will have a beta distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) for any $n > 0$.  In particular if $n > 0$ you get $f_Y(y) = (1/n) y^{1/n - 1}$ - I'm guessing you know how to compute this, you've already done the $n = 3$ case. The pdf of the $Beta(\alpha, \beta)$ distribution is $y^{\alpha-1} (1-y)^{\beta-1} / B(\alpha, \beta)$.  So matching these up you see that $Y = X^n$ has the $Beta(1/n, 1)$ distribution.